# Is it possible to customize JVM architecture for changing main() method name?

Tags: java

Can we change the name of main() method by using customization of java virtual machine architecture?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? `main(...)` is more or less a standard name across several languages.

Comment: You can create your own programming language at this point.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible by configuration. The method name and its signature are defined at the language level. See [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1) from the Java Language Specification:

> The method `main` must be declared `public`, `static`, and `void`. It must specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of `String`.